# Is List::MoreUtils::none buggy?

Tags: perl, list

I think `none` subroutine from `List::MoreUtils` does not act as described. According to documentation,

> none BLOCK LIST Logically the negation of any. Returns a true value if
>   no item in LIST meets the criterion given through BLOCK, **or if LIST
>   is empty**. Sets $_ for each item in LIST in turn

Now, try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use List::MoreUtils qw(none);

my @arr = ( 1, 2, 3 );
if ( none { $_ == 5 } @arr ) {
    say "none of the elements in arr equals 5";
}
else {
    say "some element in arr equals 5";
}
```

works OK, but replace `@arr` with an empty one (`my @arr = ();` or simply `my @arr;`) and you get a wrong answer.

What's going on?

**update: i had List::MoreUtils ver 0.22. Updated to the latest and it seems OK. Weird though!**

Comment: The implementation changed between version 0.22 and the latest - see my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is in line with the v 0.33 pure Perl [implementation](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ADAMK/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm). The reason why it failed was because the implementation changed between versions 0.22 and 0.33.

In v 0.33, if `@array` is empty, the `for` loop will not execute, so `YES` will be returned.

Here are the two versions side-by-side:

```
# v 0.33                      |  # v 0.22
------------------------------+----------------------------------------
sub none (&@) {               |  sub none (&@) {
    my $f = shift;            |      my $f = shift;
    foreach ( @_ ) {          |      return if ! @_;          # root cause
        return NO if $f->();  |      for (@_) {
    }                         |          return 0 if $f->();
    return YES;               |      }
}                             |      return 1;
                              |  }
```

---

[`MetaCPAN`](https://metacpan.org/) also provides a [comprehensive diff between versions 0.22 and 0.33](https://metacpan.org/diff/file/?target=ADAMK/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm&source=VPARSEVAL/List-MoreUtils-0.22/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm)

Comment: Cool use for SO syntax highlighting => side-by-side code comparisons :)