# How can I access older versions of CPAN modules?

Tags: perl, cpan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install a specific version of a Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260593/how-can-i-install-a-specific-version-of-a-perl-module)

There are [situations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7175937/133939) when it is useful to view older versions of CPAN source code.

Two questions:

- How can one access them? The CPAN interface is not intuitive in this regard
- Is there some canonical hyperlinking convention that can be used to differentiate between versions?

Comment: So [`BackPAN`](http://http://backpan.perl.org/) is the bicycle shop I needed. Closing question...

Comment: plz correct the link to [BackPAN](http://backpan.perl.org/)

Comment: The excellent [`MetaCPAN`](https://metacpan.org/) combines [`CPAN`](http://search.cpan.org) and [`BackPAN`](http://backpan.perl.org/) with diff capability. How cool is that!